# ¿Se puede poblar un RecyclerView con dos adapters de xml con diferente estructura?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Estoy leyendo dos xml con dos estructuras diferentes, puedo poblar un RecyclerView con los dos adapters de cada xml.

En esta imagen pueden ver lo que deseo hacer. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora tengo los archivos que son para un parser xml, una clase para cada xml, un parser para cada uno, un adapter para cada uno, lo que no sé, si puede unirlos en la clase fragment donde cargo los datos y los cargo en el recyvlerView.

Este es codigo  del fragment que estaba utilizando pero me da error y se cierra la aplicación

```
public class fqsomos  extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView reciclador,recicladorNosotros;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private adaptadorQsomos adaptador;
private adaptadorNosotros adaptadorNosotros;
private CircularProgressView loader ;
private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
ProgressDialog loading = null;
private ProgressBar spinner;
private ProgressBar spinnerNosotros;
  private final static String URL ="http://svconstructions.com.ec/sv/qsomosapp.php";
private final static String URL_nosotros ="http://svconstructions.com.ec/sv/qsomosapp.php";
private static final String LOGTAG = "LogsProyectos";
final Activity activity = getActivity();
public fqsomos() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lqsomos, container, false);
    reciclador = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    recicladorNosotros = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recicladorNosotros);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    reciclador.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recicladorNosotros.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    spinner = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressbarqsomos);
    spinnerNosotros = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressbarNosotros);
    adaptador = new adaptadorQsomos();
    adaptador.setHasStableIds(true);
    //spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE );
    reciclador.setAdapter(adaptador);
//    recicladorNosotros.setAdapter(adaptadorNosotros);
    new TareaDescargaXml_Qsomos().execute(URL);
   // new TareaDescargaXml_Nosotros().execute(URL_nosotros);
    return view;
}
public class TareaDescargaXml_Qsomos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<qsomo>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show the progress bar
        //    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    @Override
    protected List<qsomo> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return parsearXmlDeUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e( LOGTAG,"Error en la red",e);
            return null; // null si hay error de red
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e( LOGTAG,"Error al leer xml",e);
            return null; // null si hay error de parsing XML
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<qsomo> result) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE );
        // Actualizar contenido del proveedor de datos
        qsomo.Ultimas_qsomos = result;
        // Actualizar la vista del adaptador
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

private List<qsomo> parsearXmlDeUrl(String urlString)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    parseQsomos parserXml = new parseQsomos();
    List<qsomo> entries = null;

    try {
        stream = descargarContenido(urlString);
        entries = parserXml.parsear(stream);

    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    return entries;
}


// nosotros
//***************--------------------------------------*******************
public class TareaDescargaXml_Nosotros extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<nosotro>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show the progress bar
        //    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    @Override
    protected List<nosotro> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return parsearXmlDeUrlNosotros(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e( LOGTAG,"Error en la red",e);
            return null; // null si hay error de red
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e( LOGTAG,"Error al leer xml",e);
            return null; // null si hay error de parsing XML
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<nosotro> result) {
        spinnerNosotros.setVisibility(View.GONE );
        // Actualizar contenido del proveedor de datos
        nosotro.Listado_nosotros = result;
        // Actualizar la vista del adaptador
        adaptadorNosotros.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

private List<nosotro> parsearXmlDeUrlNosotros(String urlString)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    parseNosotros parserXml = new parseNosotros();
    List<nosotro> entries = null;

    try {
        stream = descargarContenido(urlString);
        entries = parserXml.parsear(stream);

    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    return entries;
}

private InputStream descargarContenido(String urlString) throws IOException {
    java.net.URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Iniciar la petición
    conn.connect();
    return conn.getInputStream();
}
```

}

y en el Layout de este fragment tengo dos recyclerView.

Comment: Hola Alldesign. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que cuentas? Poniendo quizá el comportamiento que esperas y que *no funciona* o *sí funciona*..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si buscas hacer una "lista" con elementos diferentes, lo primero que debes hacer es crear una interfaz

```
public interface Item {
    int getViewType();
}
```

Seguido de esto creamos los objetos que representan a nuestros elementos, para ejemplificar usare Item1 e Item2, ambos deben implementar la interfaz Item.

Item1

```
public class Item1 implements Item {
    private String text;

    public Item1(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Item2

```
public class Item2 implements Item {
    private String text;

    public Item2(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Ahora creamos el adaptador para el RecyclerView, el cual nos servirá para ambas vistas, cuyos Holders estan declarados dentro del mismo, es importante prestar atención en el método getViewType ya que es donde obtenemos el tipo de Item a mostrar

HetAdapter

```
public class HetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private final int ITEM1 = 1;
private final int ITEM2 = 2;

private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

public HetAdapter(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    switch (viewType){
        case ITEM1: viewHolder = new Item1Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_1,parent,false));
            break;
        case ITEM2: viewHolder = new Item2Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_2,parent,false));
            break;
        default: viewHolder = new Item1Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_1,parent));
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)){
        case ITEM1:
            Item1 item1 = (Item1) items.get(position);
            Item1Holder item1Holder = (Item1Holder)holder;
            item1Holder.text.setText(item1.getText());
            break;
        case ITEM2:
            Item2 item2 = (Item2) items.get(position);
            Item2Holder item2Holder = (Item2Holder)holder;
            item2Holder.text.setText(item2.getText());
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getViewType();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class Item1Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView text;
    public Item1Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}

class Item2Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView text;
    public Item2Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
}
```

Ahora sólo queda poblar el RecyclerView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private HetAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    items.add(new Item1("ITEM_1_1"));
    items.add(new Item2("ITEM_2_1"));
    items.add(new Item1("ITEM_1_2"));
    items.add(new Item2("ITEM_2_2"));
    items.add(new Item1("ITEM_1_3"));
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new HetAdapter(items);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Y el resultado

[image: Los layouts solo son RelativeLayout con un TextView y un ImageView acomodados de manera opuesta y con un color diferente]

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar...

Comment: Esta solución permite tener diferentes datos(objetos) en cada vista que defina o solamente es el mismo tipo diferente orden?